# Mapstruct - mapping from multiple collections into a single collection

Tags: java, mapstruct

Using MapStruct, I have two collections in my source object containing slightly different objects.  I'd like to map the objects these two collections into a common type, and then insert them all into a single collection.  Something like the below:

```
List<UserNumber> listsToDtoList(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers, List<FaxNumber> faxNumbers);

UserNumber phoneToPhoneDto(PhoneNumber phone);
UserNumber faxToPhoneDto(FaxNumber fax);
```

What's the simplest way to do this with MapStruct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I would make a mapping from my `SourceObject` (not write `List<UserNumber> listsToDtoList(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers, List<FaxNumber> faxNumbers);`

So something along the lines:

```
@Mapping( target = "userNumbers", source = "phoneNumbers" )
Target map( Source source );

@AfterMapping // will be applied in the final part of the previous method
default void map ( Source source, @MappingTarget Target target ) {
 target.getUserNumbers().addAll(source.getFaxNumbers());
}
```

Comment: This was close - but the generated code called `.clear()` on the target collection before adding the faxNumbers.  For now I've used an `@AfterMapping`, but on a custom method that just adds the fax numbers to the target collection.  If you've got any suggestions for how to use your solution, but prevent the existing collection being cleared, I'm interested to hear!

Comment: Hmmm. Forgot about that.. For the time being this is the only option. Keep an eye out for this [issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/489). Please add a comment or upvote that issue. I'll adapt my answer to reflect your solution.